# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByTitle' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, pnp, spfx-extensions

While updating item in SPFx I am getting below error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByTitle' of undefined

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below imports before updating list items:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
```

OR

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

Then you can update the list item like:

```
let list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Control Documents");

const i = await list.items.getById(itemId).update({
  BMSTwoApprovalStatus: "Retired",
});
```

**Reference**: [@pnp/sp/items - Update](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#update)